# Match handwritten kanji with template

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to match handwritten kanji with a machine-written template of the same kanji in *OpenCV*.

Until now I improved the quality of the handwritten image using `GaussianBlur`, `adaptiveThreshold` (because of uneven lighting) and some `eroding`/`dilating`. My result looks like this:

[image: handwritten kanji]

and I want to match it to a picture like this:

[image: machine-written kanji]
<sub>(source: [christian-t.com](http://www.christian-t.com/image/japanese_symbols_100/Woman_kanji.gif))</sub>

Any suggestions on what to do next? I tried SIFT but I'm not sure if it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

With hand-written character recognition, you're basically looking to match deformable shapes. There is a whole plethora of literature dedicated to matching deformable shapes, although a few stand out.

I have a couple of suggestions as a start:

1. [Shape Context](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/r.vandenboomgaard/UvAwiki/uploads/HVisser/Shape_Matching_and_Object_Recognition_Using_Shape_Contexts_Belongie_Malik_Puzicha.pdf) is a good generic algorithm that has been widely adopted for several applications including character recognition and object detection/classification/recognition.
2. [Elastic Matching](http://human.ait.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~uchida/Papers/e88-d_8_1781.pdf) has been one of the traditional approaches to solve the problem of hand-written character recognition.

If you're keen on exploring more, search for "Shape Matching" on [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com) and you'll get plenty of leads.